keychain stopped working in WSL with Ubuntu 24.10 and fish shell
I have been using keychain in fish shell to add ssh key for git for a long time.
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.10 and now it stopped working. Whenever I do a git command that require auth it will ask me for password.
I used to have this in my ~/.config/fish/conf.d/keychain.fish file
if status is-login
    and status is-interactive
    keychain --eval ~/.ssh/id_rsa | source
end

I have noted that it sets the SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID as expected.
The ssh-agent process is running, but the file that SSH_AUTH_SOCK points to in the /tmp directory does not exist. In fact, there is no directory starting with ssh- in the /tmp directory.
I have tried to remove the ~/.config/fish/conf.d/keychain.fish file, restart wsl and then when I have logged in I execute keychain --eval ~/.ssh/id_rsa | source manually.
It still can fail if I do it too quickly after starting up, but if I wait long enough everything works as expected. The SHH_AUTH_SOCK file is there and git works.
Seems to be something going on when ubuntu is starting up now? I can't quite figure it out.
It is a sort of a work-around to wait a bit and then start manually, but it would be so much nicer if I didn't have to run that command every time I start WSL.
Anyone knows why it may fail when it is started in ~/.config/fish/conf.d/keychain.fish?
Versions:
Fish: 3.7.1
Keychain: 2.8.5
Ubuntu: 24.10

Version of fish?

Version of fish is: 3.7.1
Updated the question as well

Not sure this is a fish issue because I've got the same problem in zsh killing the agent helped: https://gist.github.com/patsbin/868c48c5e8b3de1ccad7dd19257f7a17
